# How can I use p:fileUpload as a menu item to the context menu of primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

How can I use p:fileUpload as a menu item to the context menu of primefaces ?

I intend to use 'target' context menu(referred the demo) on p:graphiceImage. So each time I right-click I'll have couple of choices inside the p:contextMenu namely upload, download ,remove or something else as menu items...

Comment: like you said use Upload , Remove ... as element of context menu and every time you need to upload use a dialog , do you need an example ?!?

Comment: yes please ! @Yagami Light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say you will do it with a ContextMenu, look to this example :

***myXHTML***

Create your contextMenu :

```
<p:contextMenu   id="context"  style="width: 14%"    >
      <p:menuitem value="Upload"  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"  
       onclick="PF('dlgUpload').show();">                                        
      </p:menuitem>    
</p:contextMenu>
```

And also add the `dlgUpload` dialog :

```
<ui:define name="MyDialog">

<p:dialog header="Upload" widgetVar="dlgUpload" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" width="50%" height="40%" resizable="false">
   <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
       <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myManagedBean.uploadFile}" 
       label="Parcourir" cancelLabel="Annuler" uploadLabel="Charger" mode="advanced"  dragDropSupport="false"
       multiple="true"  
       fileLimit="3" oncomplete="PF('dlgUpload').hide();" update=":form" />            
   </h:form>
 </p:dialog>

</ui:define>
```

My advise is to always to refere to the [Primefaces ContextMenu Example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml).

And the [Primefaces Upload Example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml), and here you can look to a complete example [Upload a File Step by Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964) .

Hope that helped you.